# Why don't comets just vapourize away?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, gravity, pressure

As far as I know,  comets are in a freefall around the sun.  That would mean, net acceleration due to gravity is almost zero because R =m (g-a)   where R is reaction force.  Now pressure is force per unit area so is directly proportional to acceleration they are being pulled with.  Since the net acceleration is 0, pressure on surface should be zero as well. 
But that means they should instantly vapourize. But that doesn't seem to be the case. They only vapourize when they are near the sun.
I wanted to know why this happens or what crucial thing I am missing.

Comment: Why should they vapourize in 0 pressure? Do you think that all objects vapourize in a vacuum?

Comment: But there's nothing to push it down. Is there?  Because everything is being accelerated in same direction with same force.  So shouldn't, in lack of pressure objects turn from solid to gas?  It's even there in state curve (PT graph).

Comment: Inter-molecular forces are at work

Comment: There are strong forces between the atoms within the comet. This is what holds the object together. Imagine an astronaut in space! If it was just about external pressure, all the astronauts would now be stardust. Check the answer in this question as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178884/

Comment: But that means they should vapourize at even a very slight increase in temperature, doesn't it?

Comment: Upon temperature increase, they vapourize when the thermal energy is larger than the energy that holds the object together.

Comment: I mean,  they vapourize at a very less temperature than they would have on earth, don't they?

Comment: The pressure on the surface of a comet, asteroid, etc is (almost) zero because they are in space which is (almost perfectly) a vacuum. I don't understand why you bring gravity into it.

Comment: But they are in an orbit around the Sun, aren't they?  So why not relate that gravity and pressure,  I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Even a chunk of rock or metal evaporates, but it does so *very* slowly at standard temperature & pressure. Putting it into a vacuum speeds up the process, but it's still very slow. Comets generally have a lot of volatiles like ice & frozen gases, so they evaporate faster than rocks, especially when warmed by the sun.